# SwiftUI + iOS17 – Text animation issues with opacity applied

Tags: animation, swiftui, text, opacity, ios17

I am currently investigating an animation issue on iOS17 and discovered some behaviour different compared to iOS16 that I'm trying to understand. I've debugged this down to the fact that iOS17 behaves differently when certain modifiers are applied to a `Text`, such as `.opacity` or `.blur`, and then a text change is animated.

### Text without .opacity

```
@State var text = "Start"
    
var body: some View {
    Text(text)
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1.0), value: text)
        .background(Color.red)
        .onAppear {
            text = "Text after animation"
        }
}
```

##### Result

The result:

[image]

### Text with .opacity

Now consider the same code, but with an opacity modifier applied:

```
@State var text = "Start"
    
var body: some View {
    Text(text)
        .opacity(0.5)
        .animation(.linear(duration: 1.0), value: text)
        .background(Color.red)
        .onAppear {
            text = "Text after animation"
        }
}
```

##### Result

The result on iOS16 is the same as above. **On iOS17, however, this is the result:**
[image]

So I have two basic questions:

- Is this some change on Apples side I missed? Can someone explain why this behaves differently?
- In my opinion, the new result of iOS17 is undesired – if I have text changes I usually want to cross-fade the text without it moving. I have a production app where this causes tiny movements of text that just look not clean. How can I get the iOS16 animation back on iOS17?

Comment: Have you tried moving the animation modifier up and/or down? That can change behavior

Comment: Also try changing the multi line text alignment to center. It seems like the anchor is what changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I tried `.multilineTextAlignment` but it doesn't seem to change anything. Moving the animation modifier above .opacity basically has the same result, except the text movement is not animated ("Start" just jumps to the left now, which is also not a clean animation)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can force a change of id every time the view is repainted:

```swift
Text(text)
    .id(UUID()) // <- ADDED
    .opacity(0.5)
    .animation(.linear(duration: 5.0), value: text)
    .background(Color.red)
    .onAppear {
        text = "Text after animation"
    }
```

I suppose, what this gives you is a transition from the old view to the new view, rather than an animated change to an existing view.

Comment: Yes thank you this at least gives me a decent animation! In my (production) case I had to wrap the Text in an HStack(spacing: 0) for some reason, then apply the `.id` to the text and the `.animation` to the HStack.

Tip: You can use `.id(text)` to avoid unnecessary redraw of the text.

Comment: Pleased to hear you found a workaround! Yes, I thought about using the string as the id, just wasn't sure whether this was a good idea if there might be duplicate cases. Ps. You are welcome to upvote the answer if it helped ;)